# Cannot put a layer name as the same as the raster name just created by Python script

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, error-000582

I have a question regarding Python script for making a Heat Map Tool.

I  am making a Heat Map Tool where users can set the map extent, the tool will read the current scale of the map, then make a raster heat map layer using appropriate cell size and search radius depend on the map scale, and the new raster layer will appear on the TOC of the map document. I succeeded this part. 
But I also put a function that users can set the raster name, and the name will appear as a layer name too.

The script is the below.

```
# Script arguments
heatMapTest2 = Output_Raster_Layer
heatMapTest2Name = 'Output Raster'
templist = heatMapTest2.split("\\")
layername = templist[-1]
MXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(MXD)[0]
mapExtent = dataFrame.extent
scale = dataFrame.scale
Input_Layer_2 = Input_Layer

#Add new layer to the dataframe
result = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(heatMapTest2, layername)
lyrLayer = result.getOutput(0)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dataFrame, lyrLayer, "AUTO_ARRANGE")
```

This function does work if I use the ArcGIS from the remote, and the work environment is the same server as the remote. 
But I set the work environment in different server, it gives me an error message as the below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Q:\GIS_Tools\HeatMapTool\Python\HeatMapTool_Incidents_Add_Reclass_para5_short.py", line 149, in <module>
    result = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(heatMapTest2, layername)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6479, in MakeRasterLayer
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000582: Error occurred during execution.
Failed to execute (HeatMapAllWithOutputLayerPara).
```

Is there anybody who can tell why that happened?

Comment: [Error 000582](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00vp00000015000582.htm) isn't the most informative message, but it probably has to do with your parameters. Are they both absolute paths?

Comment: What if you `import os` and instead of creating `templist` and using its last value (which is somewhat error-prone), you do `layername = os.path.basename(heatMapTest2)`? Does your output filename have an extension (e.g. '.tif')?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the parameters are only relative to where the .py file exists.  Maybe you could get the input parameters from a [script tool form](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00150000002q000000)?